# YUI Test and DOM testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, yui

The YUI Test page says that YUI suports "DOM Event simulation in all A-grade browsers (through Event)."  I can't find much more detail beyond this.  Does this mean the DOM is "reset" between tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means there's a `node.simulate('click')` method that helps you automate tests

You can get more information at: [Simulating DOM Events](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/simulate.html).